# Full page orientation change

Tags: xetex, koma-script, landscape, scrlayer-scrpage

I am trying to to change a full page orientation with text, header and footer.

I found that using KOMA scripts is working better that lscape in my case, especially with header / footer orientation. See [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384289/change-page-orientation-inside-document).

Now before sending the document to the printer I'd like to make sure that all pages have the same orientation. I other word is there a portable option to change page orientation in PDF without playing around with `pdfpageattr` which is not supported by xetex or `\PLS@Rotate` which can be tricky with odd / even pages?

Thanks in advance.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[usegeometry]{typearea}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[hmargin=.65in,vmargin=1.1in]{geometry}

\usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

%% \usepackage{pdflscape}

\KOMAoptions{headsepline=false}
\ihead[]{ihead}
\chead[]{chead}
\ohead[]{ohead}
\ifoot[]{ifoot}
\cfoot[]{cfoot}
\ofoot[]{ofoot}


\usepackage{blindtext}%

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mylandscape}{%
  %% \PLS@Rotate{90}
  \cleardoublepage%
  \KOMAoptions{paper=landscape, pagesize}%
  \recalctypearea%
  \newgeometry{hmargin=.65in,vmargin=1.1in}%
}%
\newcommand{\myportrait}{%    
  %% \PLS@Rotate{0}
  \cleardoublepage%
  \KOMAoptions{paper=portrait}%
  \recalctypearea%
  \newgeometry{hmargin=.65in,vmargin=1.1in}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\myportrait
\Blindtext
\mylandscape
\Blindtext
\newpage
\myportrait
\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

Result:
[image: Result]

And expected result:
[image: Expected result]

Comment: If you do not want pages in landscape orientation it would be better to use a package like `lscape`, because `typearea`'s option `pagesize` really changes the physical page dimensions and so the page orientation not only the orientation of the page content.

Comment: I tried both `lscape` and `pdflscape` and they are doing the job but for neither headers nor footers since they are only manipulating the text orientation.

Comment: Maybe I do not understand your problem, but don't you want all pages printed in portrait orientation? In this case the page header and footer should not be in landscape orientation, because these are made mainly for reader orientation while thumbing through the document, e.g. while searching for a page or heading.

Comment: Moreover, if it is not because of binding all pages in portrait but only for printing: Select auto-rotate option in the printer menu or the driver menu.

Comment: I want the result like the "expected result" picture. By printer I mean a printing service such as lulu or any other similar provider. Maybe it's just a display matter but having both portrait and landscape pages in a PDF document is a bit disturbing.

Answer (score 1):

Note that your desired result is  unusual for a printed document: headers and footers should not change their position even if the content of a page is rotated.

You could use package `pdfpages` in a second file to get the desired result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,rotateoversize]{document.pdf}% use the name of your document
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: It's for a coil bounded book with some pages meant to be read in portrait others in landscape. This seems to add a complexity level. Meanwhile my original solution was to add a `\PLS@AddRotate{-90}` for landscape and `\PLS@RemoveRotate` for portrait. It works I was just wondering if KOMA scripts does handle this case or not. I guess the answer is no.

Comment: @renard As already told, for a bounded book page header and footer should always be readable without rotating the book or bend your neck ;-) . This could be one reason why KOMA-Script does not provide this. Or maybe in more than 24 years nobody has asked for this or at least not enough persons have asked for it.